# JSP exception : no getter method for the property

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am using struts with JSP. I have the below form bean.

```
<form-bean name="editProjectForm" dynamic="true" type="com.thomsonrights.base.BaseDynaValidatorFormForProject">
    <form-property name="mutable" type="java.lang.String" initial="true" />
    <form-property name="method" type="java.lang.String"  />
    <form-property name="mod_time_stamp" type="java.lang.String"  initial="" />
    <form-property name="pub_id" type="java.lang.String"  initial="" /> 

    <form-property name="proj_complete_name" type="java.lang.String"  />
    <form-property name="proj_owner_list" type="java.lang.Object"  />
    <form-property name="proj_user_list" type="java.lang.Object[]"  />
    <form-property name="pub_authors_list" type="java.lang.Object[]"  />

  </form-bean>
```

In the Jsp am using the below tag.

In the action class, I am setting proj_owner_list object in the form.

```
 ProjOwner projOwner = ProjectFunctions.retrieveProjOwnerInfo(conn, form, sql);
 PropertyUtils.setProperty(form, "proj_owner_list", projOwner );
```

While editing the page OR after saving, the values rendered correctly and displayed in the UI. But at the time of saving, if validation fails, then am getting the below error.

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property
>   proj_owner_list.name of bean editProjectForm

Comment: have you created the getter and setter method for the field in the bean

Comment: yes i have the getter setter for ProjOwner

Comment: Am using this tag in JSP
<bean:write name="editProjectForm" property="proj_owner_list.name" />

Comment: if you have getter setter, make sure it's public

Comment: as per my thinking. ProjOwner is an object of the class and in that class you have multiple parameter including name. am i going in right direction or not

Comment: yes you are correct....In ProjOwner i have fields like name,etc,, and also getter setter for the fields... 

It is working fine in normal scenario>... The problem occurs only if the validation fails

Comment: Show your getter, your object type, your interceptor stack, your validation. And please, consider abandoning the whole set of bad practices you're into: `<form:` instead of `<:s`, snake_case instead of camelCase, etc..

Comment: <bean:write name="employee" property="firstName" ignore="true"/>

Comment: package com.thomsonrights.dbmodel;

    public class ProjOwner {

 public String name;
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

Comment: @mayank I have one object in the form. Within the object, i have fields like name, etc... Everything is working fine in normal scenario. But if page level validation fails, am getting the error.

Comment: I mean edit your question and add all the needed code to understand the problem. Also why are you using the bean tag ? Remove it